# MB can handle more lanes than the CPU afford (For multi-GPU configuration)

Tags: cpu, motherboard, pci-express

I'm building a 4 GPU PC. During my research I was surprised, the manual of an potential motherboard says that a 40 CPU lane can handle four x16 PCIe slots. Can someone explain me how it works ? I thought `1 CPU lane = 1 PCIe lane`. When you build powerful computers, it's important to understand where are the bottle necks, or you will waste money.

The text in the manual:

> 40-LANE CPU
>
> 7 x PCI Express 3.0/2.0 x16 slots* (single at x16, dual at x16/x16, triple at x16/x16/x16, quad at x16/x16/x16/x16, seven at x16/x8/x8/x8/x8/x8/X8)

The link to the manual: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/Socket2011-R3/X99-E_WS/Manual/E13676_X99-E_WS_UM_V4_WEB.pdf (warning: the English version have some errors, the 40-lane and 28-lane CPU are not comparable. In the Chinese version you can see the real 4 way with 28-lane CPU `四張採 x16/x8/x8/x8`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the motherboard diagram, we can see there is a chip between CPU and PCIe slots
[image]

This PLX chip does multiplexing. It doesn't create new lanes. So to make it simple, in worst case we are not faster than our 40 CPU lanes. But when a GPU2 has already all his data transfered, GPU1 can passe from x8 to x16 for example. If you want to have more details about how PLX chip work, this article is very nice https://www.anandtech.com/show/6170/four-multigpu-z77-boards-from-280350-plx-pex-8747-featuring-gigabyte-asrock-ecs-and-evga

I want to thanks the Asus support for giving me the motherboard diagram.